# Why pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples changes the order of the tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When create a multiindex using from_tuples, the create index object has a different order than the input tuple

I am trying to add a column level to a data frame, using pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples method, but the levels is different from what I expected.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_1':[1, 2], 'x_2':[3, 4], 'x_10':[3, 4], 'y_1':[5, 6], 'y_2':[7, 8], 'y_10':[1, 2]})
df = df.reindex(columns=['x_1', 'x_2', 'x_10', 'y_1', 'y_2', 'y_10'])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_')) for c in df.columns])
print(index)

MultiIndex(levels=[['x', 'y'], ['1', '10', '2']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1]])
```

When I add the level to the dataframe and perform stacking, the order is not what I want.

```
df.columns = index
df.stack()

      x  y
0 1   1  5
  10  3  1
  2   3  7
1 1   2  6
  10  4  2
  2   4  8
```

I expect the index levels look like:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['x', 'y'], ['1', '2', '10']])
```

and stacking will look like the following:

```
df.stack()
      x  y
0 1   1  5
  2   3  7
  10  3  1
1 1   2  6
  2   4  8
  10  4  2
```

Comment: isn't this ordering according to the fact it's a string rather than integer? e.g. '1','10', and then '2' is ordered like this as they are string

Comment: I agree that is true, is there anyway to make it specific order?

Comment: You can reindex after the fact to achieve the desired order, however, this introduces performance issues as the index is expected to be ordered, if you have integer columns then this would just work, it's up to you

Answer (score 2):

You can [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) at a specific level, passing the level values from your column prior to the call to `stack`:

```
In[177]:
df.stack().reindex(df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique(), level=1)
Out[177]: 
      x  y
0 1   1  5
  2   3  7
  10  3  1
1 1   2  6
  2   4  8
  10  4  2
```

Note that this has performance issues because an index is expected to be sorted for fast lookups

Answer (score 1):

The index you have constructed is actually ordered as specified. When you `print(index)` you are seeing how Pandas stores the index *internally*. Using `index.values` unravels this representation to give an array of indices aligned with your dataframe.

```
print(index.values)
# array([('x', '1'), ('x', '2'), ('x', '10'), ('y', '1'), ('y', '2'),
#        ('y', '10')], dtype=object)

df.columns = index 
print(df)    
#    x        y      
#    1  2 10  1  2 10
# 0  1  3  3  5  7  1
# 1  2  4  4  6  8  2
```

---

The real issue is [`pd.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) applies sorting and, since you have defined strings, `'10'` comes before `'2'`. To maintain ordering as you desire *after* `stack`, make sure you use integers:

```
def splitter(x):
    strng, num = x.split('_')
    return strng, int(num)

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns.map(splitter))

df.columns = index 
print(df.stack())
#       x  y
# 0 1   1  5
#   2   3  7
#   10  3  1
# 1 1   2  6
#   2   4  8
#   10  4  2
```